# How can I find an address with latitude and longitude of one point in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I know that for each pair of latitude and longitude one point of map
is coordinated and one marker can be shown for it so every body can
find lat & long of each point in map, but I don't know reverse of this
feature is possible?! I mean that can I get the address of one place
with knowing lat&long of it (a text format of address not screenshot
of marker location!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) component to send a request with only LatLng set and get the address from the result object in `formatted_address` as explained on the page.

Answer (score 2):

The term is reverse geocoding, and here is an example which uses Gmaps v3

http://demos.projectx.co.nz/gmaps3/reverse_geocoder.html

Just look at the source code.